# Can I use data loader without batching

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, dataloader

What I am really interested in with data-loader is the per request caching. For example say my graphql query needs to call getUser("id1") 3x. I would like something to dedupe that call.

However it seems like with data-loader I need to pass in an array of keys into my batch function, and multiple requests will be batched into one api calls.

This has me making a few assumptions that i dont like:

1.) That each service I am calling has a batch api (some of the ones im dealing with do not).

2.) What if multiple calls get batched into 1 api call, and that call fails because 1 of the items was not found. Normally I could handle this by returning null for that field, and that could be a valid case. Now however my entire call may fail, if the batch API decides to throw an error since 1 item was not found.

Is there anyway to use dataloader with single-key requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both assumptions are wrong because the implementation of the batch function is ultimately left up to you. As indicated in the [documentation](https://github.com/graphql/dataloader#batch-function), the only requirements when writing your batch function are as follows:

> A batch loading function accepts an Array of keys, and returns a Promise which resolves to an Array of values or Error instances.

So there's no need for the underlying data source to also accept an array of IDs. And there's no need for one or more failed calls to cause the whole function to throw since you can return either null or an error instance for any particular ID in the array you return. In fact, your batch function should *never* throw and instead should always return an array of one or more errors.

In other words, your implementation of the batch function might look something like:

```
async function batchFn (ids) {
  const result = await Promise.all(ids.map(async (id) => {
    try {
      const foo = await getFooById(id)
      return foo
    } catch (e) {
      // either return null or the error
    }
  }))
}
```

It's worth noting that it's also possible to set the `maxBatchSize` to `1` to effectively disable batching. However, this doesn't change the requirements for how your batch function is implemented -- it always needs to take an array of IDs and always needs to return an array of values/errors of the same length as the array of IDs.

Comment: makes sense. 

But if I am still making a http call per id, is there really any point to batching?

Comment: No, there's not. But DataLoader was designed as a tool specifically for batching and you're trying to use it without so... this is what you're left with :) If all you need is per-request caching, it's be simple enough to roll your own. You just create a function that takes an id and returns a Promise with the result, then [memoize it](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#memoize), taking care to recreate the memoized functions on each request (i.e. inside your context function).

Comment: Gotchu. My biggest issue right now is not around batching, but rather around field resolvers re-requesting data that was already available in the root query. You are write it might be easier to roll my own memoization. Or store the common data in some intermediate model.

Comment: If the data is already in the parent object, you can also just conditionally check for it inside your resolver: `(parent) => return parent.someField || fetchFromDataSource()`. Anyway, good luck. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted if it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel's solution is perfectly fine and is in fact what I've used so far, after extracting it into a helper function.
But I just found another solution that does not require that much boilerplate code.

```
new DataLoader<string, string>(async ([key]) => [await getEntityById(key)], {batch: false});
```

When we set `batch: false` then we should always get a key-array of size one passed as argument. We can therefore simply destructure it and return a one-sized array with the data. Notice the brackets arround the return value! If you omit those, this could go horribly wrong e.g. for string values.